# Как отменить действие кода # @hidden_cell в jupyter notebook? python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Хотела спрятать длинный код, поэтому ввела в ячейку код:

```
# @hidden_cell
```

Могу их скрывать, как и хотела, но у меня перестали работать графики типа fig = px.bar, до ввода всё работало. Теперь при открытии новой тетрадки автоматически появляется эта функция, а графики так же не отображаются, только появляется пустое пространство с размером графика. По ощущениям я что-то установила, но расширения вроде все те же... Как можно это убрать?